# Why photoimages don't exist?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I will show a reduced portion of the code that gives me a problem.

`_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimageN" doesn't exist` - where N stays for 1, 2, 3, etc...

There is a first class that shows a menu using an image in the background.

```
class MenuWindow():    #in this class we show the main part of the program
    def __init__(self):
        self.Menu=Tk()
        self.MCanvas=Canvas(self.Menu)
        self.MCanvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>",self.MenuClick)

        #unuseful lines that configure the window and the canvas#

        self.Background=PhotoImage(height=600,width=700)#a simple tkinter.PhotoImage object

        #other unuseful lines that draw the photoimage ( without reading any file, with the method put())#

        self.MCanvas.create_image((x,y),image=self.Background,state="normal")

        #unuseful lines that continue the drawing of the canvas#
```

And a second class that shows another window, using another image in the background. This class is launched by the first class via click binding of the function self.MenuClick.

```
class EditorWindow():    #in this class we show the main part of the program
    def __init__(self):
        self.Eenu=Tk()
        self.ECanvas=Canvas(self.Eenu)

        #unuseful lines that configure the window and the canvas#

        self.Background=PhotoImage(height=600,width=700)

        #other unuseful lines that draw the photoimage ( without reading any file , with the method put() )#

        self.ECanvas.create_image((x,y),image=self.Background,state="normal")#in this line i get the error

        #unuseful lines that continue the drawing of the canvas#
```

The complere traceback is the following:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1399, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/albertoperrella/Desktop/slay.py", line 70, in MenuClick
    EditorWindow(self)
  File "/Users/albertoperrella/Desktop/slay.py", line 85, in __init__
    self.ECanvas.create_image((3,3),image=self.Background,state="normal",anchor="nw")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2140, in create_image
    return self._create('image', args, kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2131, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
```

The two classes are made in a similar way, so I don't know why I get the error with the second one. I am sure that it isn't a writing error e.g.(conttruct instead of construct) and that the images I am using actually exist.

So I think that:

- I am making some concept mistakes,
- or it is a bug (or subtle behaviour of Tkinter) in python.

Comment: which line raises the error?  Can you post the traceback?

Comment: I think more details of `PhotoImage()` are needed, since that seems to be where the image is coming from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved myself the problem :

The second class I defined was the problem cause it used another root window, alias Tk(). An equivalent to the normal Tk() window is the Toplevel() that is the same as a root but hasn't its own interpreter context.

Shortly, to solve the problem I had to change the first line of the **init**() method of the EditorWindow class from

```
        self.Eenu=Tk()
```

to

```
        self.Eenu=Toplevel()
```

Comment: Correct - you cannot have two instances of `Tk`. One instance, and call `mainloop` exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `master` argument in `ImageTk.PhotoImage()` to the respective window, like this:

```py
ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("photo.png"), master=self.window)
```

And everything will be alright.