# Link between two scripts on a button click in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two files in my directory (`first.py` and `second.py`). The `first.py` has a button. So on clicking the button in `first.py` gui window, it should be directed to `second.py` gui window.
[first.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlCTt.jpg)  window photo and [second.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PywrN.jpg)  window photo. So  on clicking the sign up button in the first.py, it should go to the sign up page in second.py.

How to do the connection or linking between the two scripts?

first.py

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
root.title("My Bank")
root.geometry("500x500")

photo=tk.PhotoImage(file="image1.gif")
label = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
label.image = photo
label.pack()
label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

tfm = tk.Frame(root, width=2000, height=50)
tfm.pack(side=tk.TOP)

w = tk.Label(tfm, text="MY bank", font=("Times", "24", "bold"), bg="yellow", anchor="e", fg="black", padx=350, pady=10)
w.pack(fill="both")

bfm = tk.Frame(root, width=2000, height=50, bg="gray")
bfm.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

w = tk.Label(root, text="Main Menu", font=("Times", "24", "bold"), bg="black", fg="white", padx=350, pady=10)
w.pack(padx=10, pady=30)

button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Sign Up", width=12, height=1, bg="black",fg="white", bd="8", font=("Helvetica", "12", "bold"))
button1.pack(padx=10, pady=10) 

button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Sign In",  width=12, height=1, 
bg="black",fg="white", bd="8",  font=("Helvetica", "12", "bold"))
button2.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

button3 = tk.Button(root, text="Admin Sign In", width=12, height=1, bg="black",fg="white", bd="8",  font=("Helvetica", "12", "bold"))
button3.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

button4 = tk.Button(root, text="Quit!",  width=5, height=1, bg="black",fg="white", bd="10",  font=("Helvetica", "12", "bold"))
button4.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

second.py

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
root.title("My Bank")
root.geometry("500x500")

photo=tk.PhotoImage(file="image1.gif")
label = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
label.image = photo
label.pack()
label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

tfm = tk.Frame(root, width=2000, height=50)
tfm.pack(side=tk.TOP)

w = tk.Label(tfm, text="MY bank", font=("Times", "24", "bold"), bg="yellow", anchor="e", fg="black", padx=350, pady=10)
w.pack(fill="both")

bfm = tk.Frame(root, width=2000, height=50, bg="gray")
bfm.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

w = tk.Label(root, text="Sign Up", font=("Times", "24", "bold"), bg="black", fg="white", padx=350, pady=10)
w.pack(padx=10, pady=30)

e1 = tk.Entry(root, width=20,   font=("Times", "14", "bold"), bd=3, fg="blue")
e1.insert(0, 'Username')
e1.pack(padx=150, pady=10)

e2 = tk.Entry(root, width=20,   font=("Times", "14", "bold"), bd=3, fg="blue")
e2.insert(0, 'Email')
e2.pack(padx=150, pady=10)

e3 = tk.Entry(root, width=20,   font=("Times", "14", "bold"), bd=3, fg="blue")
e3.insert(0, 'Password')
e3.pack(padx=150, pady=10)

button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Sign Up", width=12, height=1, bg="black",fg="white", bd="8", font=("Helvetica", "12", "bold"))
button1.pack(padx=100, pady=20) 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What exactly does "**it** should be directed to `second.py` gui window" mean? What happens to the first window? Have you tried writing any code, and if so, why isn't it in your question?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: I've posted the window pictures of first.py and second.py

Comment: We don’t need pictures, we need to see your code.

Comment: I've posted the code. Please do help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through your problem and I guess you want to open another file when the button is clicked. To do this you need to import the file which you want to load on button click. And create another `tkinter` function in the external script. While running through your code i even came across the error which is `tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage3" doesn't exist` as of now I even fixed this for more information visit [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097811/image-pyimage2-doesnt-exist). Here is the code which i made all the changes.

```
    """
Spyder Editor

This is a temporary script file.
"""
import second
import tkinter as tk



root=tk.Toplevel()
root.title("My Bank")
root.geometry("500x500")

photo=tk.PhotoImage(file="image1.gif")
label = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
label.image = photo
label.pack()
label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

tfm = tk.Frame(root, width=2000, height=50)
tfm.pack(side=tk.TOP)

w = tk.Label(tfm, text="MY bank", font=("Times", "24", "bold"), bg="yellow", anchor="e", fg="black", padx=350, pady=10)
w.pack(fill="both")

bfm = tk.Frame(root, width=2000, height=50, bg="gray")
bfm.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

w = tk.Label(root, text="Main Menu", font=("Times", "24", "bold"), bg="black", fg="white", padx=350, pady=10)
w.pack(padx=10, pady=30)

button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Sign Up", command=lambda : second.signup() , width=12, height=1, bg="black",fg="white", bd="8", font=("Helvetica", "12", "bold"))
button1.pack(padx=10, pady=10) 

button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Sign In",  width=12, height=1, 
bg="black",fg="white", bd="8",  font=("Helvetica", "12", "bold"))
button2.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

button3 = tk.Button(root, text="Admin Sign In", width=12, height=1, bg="black",fg="white", bd="8",  font=("Helvetica", "12", "bold"))
button3.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

button4 = tk.Button(root, text="Quit!",  width=5, height=1, bg="black",fg="white", bd="10",  font=("Helvetica", "12", "bold"))
button4.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

and the other one

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon May  7 11:09:28 2018

@author: kedar
"""

import tkinter as tk

def signup():

    root=tk.Toplevel()
    root.title("My Bank")
    root.geometry("500x500")

    photo=tk.PhotoImage(file="image1.gif")
    label = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
    label.image = photo
    label.pack()
    label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    tfm = tk.Frame(root, width=2000, height=50)
    tfm.pack(side=tk.TOP)

    w = tk.Label(tfm, text="MY bank", font=("Times", "24", "bold"), bg="yellow", anchor="e", fg="black", padx=350, pady=10)
    w.pack(fill="both")

    bfm = tk.Frame(root, width=2000, height=50, bg="gray")
    bfm.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

    w = tk.Label(root, text="Sign Up", font=("Times", "24", "bold"), bg="black", fg="white", padx=350, pady=10)
    w.pack(padx=10, pady=30)

    e1 = tk.Entry(root, width=20,   font=("Times", "14", "bold"), bd=3, fg="blue")
    e1.insert(0, 'Username')
    e1.pack(padx=150, pady=10)

    e2 = tk.Entry(root, width=20,   font=("Times", "14", "bold"), bd=3, fg="blue")
    e2.insert(0, 'Email')
    e2.pack(padx=150, pady=10)

    e3 = tk.Entry(root, width=20,   font=("Times", "14", "bold"), bd=3, fg="blue")
    e3.insert(0, 'Password')
    e3.pack(padx=150, pady=10)

    button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Sign Up", width=12, height=1, bg="black",fg="white", bd="8", font=("Helvetica", "12", "bold"))
    button1.pack(padx=100, pady=20) 

    root.mainloop()
```

For now you can just copy this and use it. I hope it helps.