# I'm Getting a Tkinter error when calling a function in a graphic menu

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

**I have a function which when called, Doesn't work while other functions in the same indentation work perfectly
This is the function
I've tried a lot of things but they don't seem to work**

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
from tkinter import messagebox 
import tkinter.font as font 
import mysql.connector as mys 
import time 
from time import sleep 
def Assign():
    # TE  Text Entry
    # TEfn  Text Entry Flight number
    # TEp Text Entry Passengers
    # TEa Text Entry Airport
    # TEd Text Entry Distance
    def computing():
        master=Tk()
        master.title('AMAS')
        photo=PhotoImage(file='AMAS.gif') #Image must be GIF
        Label(image=photo) # Line required to prevent python's garbage dump function 
        Label(master,image=photo,fg='black',bg='black').grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=E)
        master.resizable(0,0) # Optional line to prevent the user from resizing the window
        master.mainloop()
        
    def dwindow():
        print('dwindow called')#TEMP
        def saveTEd():
            global Ed
            Ed=TEd.get()
            print(Ed)
            window.destroy()
    # Window Number 5 Called Below
            computing()
        window=Tk()
        window.title("Distance")
        window.configure(background='white')
        photo1=PhotoImage(file='Distance.gif')
        Label(image=photo1)
        Label(window,image=photo1,bg='white').grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
        Label(window,text='Enter The Distance Travelled',bg='white',fg='black',font='none 12 bold').grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)
        TEd=Entry(window,width=20,bg='white')
        TEd.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
        Button(window,text='Enter',width=6,command=saveTEd).grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W)
        mainloop()

    def awindow():
        print('awindow called')#TEMP
        def saveDDMo(value):
            global DDMo
            DDMo=aoption.get()
            print(DDMo)
            window.destroy()
    # Window Number 4 Called Below
            dwindow()
        window=Tk()
        window.title("Destination Airport")
        window.configure(background='white')
        photo1=PhotoImage(file='airport.gif')
        Label(image=photo1)
        Label(window,image=photo1,bg='white').grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
        Label(window,text='Enter The Destination',bg='white',fg='black',font='none 12 bold').grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)
        OPTIONS = ['Select an option','BNE','MEL','SYD','BAH','BRU','YYZ','PEK','PVG','CAI','MUC','ATH','AMD','BLR','DEL','COK','CCU','CCJ','BOM','TRV','CGK','NBO','KWI','LHR','MAN','ORG','LAX','JFK','DCA']
        aoption = StringVar(window)
        aoption.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default value
        OptionMenu(window, aoption, *OPTIONS,command=saveDDMo).grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
        mainloop()
       


    def pwindow():
        print('pwindow called')#TEMP
        def saveTEp():
            global Ep
            Ep=TEp.get()
            print(Ep)
            window.destroy()
    # Window Number 3 Called Below
            awindow()
        window=Tk()
        window.title("Passengers")
        window.configure(background='white')
        photo1=PhotoImage(file='passengers.gif')
        Label(image=photo1)
        Label(window,image=photo1,bg='white').grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
        Label(window,text='Enter The Number Of Passengers',bg='white',fg='black',font='none 12 bold').grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)
        TEp=Entry(window,width=20,bg='white')
        TEp.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
        Button(window,text='Enter',width=6,command=saveTEp).grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W)
        mainloop()
    def fnwindow():
        def saveTEfn():
            global Efn
            Efn=TEfn.get()
            print(Efn)
            window.destroy()
    # Window Number 2 Called Below
            pwindow()
        window=Tk()
        window.title("Flight Number")
        window.configure(background='white')
        photo1=PhotoImage(file='flightnumber.gif')
        Label(image=photo1)
        Label(window,image=photo1,bg='white').grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
        Label(window,text='Enter the Flight Number',background='white',foreground='black',font='none 12 bold').grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)
        TEfn=Entry(window,width=20,bg='white')
        TEfn.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
        Button(window,text='Enter',width=6,command=saveTEfn).grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W)
        Label.pack()
        mainloop()
    # Window Number 1 Called below
    fnwindow()

#The error:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\vinayak\Documents\Programs 12th\Project.py", line 414, in Assign
    fnwindow()
  File "C:\Users\vinayak\Documents\Programs 12th\Project.py", line 406, in fnwindow
    Label(window,image=photo1,bg='white').grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
  File "C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2766, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\vinayak\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
```

I think it might be because of what I'm importing or garbage dump but I can't seem to resolve the issue.

---

I think it might be because of what I'm importing or garbage dump but I can't seem to resolve the issue.
I think it might be because of what I'm importing or garbage dump but I can't seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26097811/9896377

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here is `image "pyimage2" doesn't exist`

Have you tried refering to this? [StackOverflow-'image “pyimage2” doesn't exist'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097811/image-pyimage2-doesnt-exist)

In short, You can't have two instances of Tk() running simultaneously, you have to use Toplevel() instead.