# How to add images inside another window using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

So when I create a window and add an image it works. But then I create a window inside a function and it shows `image "pyimage2" doesn't exist`. I tried adding the image as a global variable but that doesn't work either (Read on another post that it's a possible fix).

Without global variable:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
os.chdir("C:/Users/flare/Desktop/moi/folders/some_files/soundbar program/")


main=tk.Tk()
background=tk.PhotoImage(file="resources/dark_grey_bg.png")
background_label=tk.Label(main,image=background)
background_label.place(x=0,y=0)

def another():
    anotherwindow=tk.Tk()
    bg=tk.PhotoImage(file="resources/light_grey_bg.png")
    bg_label=tk.Label(anotherwindow,image=bg)
    bg_label.place(x=0,y=0)
    anotherwindow.mainloop()

another()
main.mainloop()
```

With global variable:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
global bg
os.chdir("C:/Users/flare/Desktop/moi/folders/some_files/soundbar program/")


main=tk.Tk()
background=tk.PhotoImage(file="resources/dark_grey_bg.png")
background_label=tk.Label(main,image=background)
background_label.place(x=0,y=0)

def another():
    global bg
    anotherwindow=tk.Tk()
    bg=tk.PhotoImage(file="resources/light_grey_bg.png")
    bg_label=tk.Label(anotherwindow,image=bg)
    bg_label.place(x=0,y=0)
    anotherwindow.mainloop()

another()
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `tkinter.Toplevel` for all windows after the first

Comment: Also it is not recommended to call `mainloop()` more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Posted here: [Why photoimages don't exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800007/why-photoimages-dont-exist)

"The second class I defined was the problem cause it used another root window, alias Tk(). An equivalent to the normal Tk() window is the Toplevel() that is the same as a root but hasn't its own interpreter context."

Change the second window to `TopLevel()`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
os.chdir("C:/Users/flare/Desktop/moi/folders/some_files/soundbar program/")


main=tk.Tk()
background=tk.PhotoImage(file="resources/dark_grey_bg.png")
background_label=tk.Label(main,image=background)
background_label.place(x=0,y=0)

def another():
    anotherwindow=tk.Toplevel()
    bg=tk.PhotoImage(file="resources/light_grey_bg.png")
    bg_label=tk.Label(anotherwindow,image=bg)
    bg_label.place(x=0,y=0)
    anotherwindow.mainloop()

another()
main.mainloop()
```